# rolling back database changes, from a remote REST API test case call

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

Our project is built with spring boot. Within this project, we've built lot of REST API implementations using the java language, with REST APIs being invocable at URI end-points. Many of these REST API implementations, interact with RDBMS database at back-end (we're using postgresql). The response of all our REST APIs is JSON.

I'm writing API tests that test these REST APIs, using java within the test case, and using JUnit library to write these tests.

I'm writing two kinds of these API tests, as follows,

1) For the REST APIs, that only do read from the database, the test case implementation is simple. I use an HTTP client library from java within my test case, and issue a GET or POST request. I then do 'assert' on the returned JSON response within the test case.

2) For the REST APIs, that do one of create, update or delete on the database, I'm facing challenges to roll back from the database create, update or delete changes that my test case does. In fact, at this moment, I don't know how to roll back create, update or delete changes that my test case does, just before my test case exits. Can anyone please give pointers how to solve this?

Below is also mentioned present source code of one of my test case,

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.AfterClass;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;

    public class ApplnCommonRestControllerTest {
        private static String API_URI_2 = "http://localhost:8081/appln-restapis/rest/public/common/getalluniversities";
        private static CloseableHttpClient fHttpClient;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            fHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            fHttpClient.close();
        }

        @Test
        public void getAllUniversitiesResponseBodyTest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {        
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(API_URI_2);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = fHttpClient.execute(httpGet);

            InputStream inpStream = (httpResponse.getEntity()).getContent();        
            String respBodyJsonString = Utilities.inputStreamToString(inpStream);
            JSONObject jsonResponeObj = new JSONObject(respBodyJsonString);
            JSONArray dataJsonArray = jsonResponeObj.getJSONArray("data");        

            assertTrue(dataJsonArray.length() >= 2);   // test that array contains at least two elements

            JSONObject arrElem = (JSONObject)dataJsonArray.get(0);   // test first element of array
            int univId = arrElem.getInt("id");
            String univName = arrElem.getString("universityname");
            assertTrue(univId == 1 && univName.length() > 0);

            arrElem = (JSONObject)dataJsonArray.get(dataJsonArray.length() - 1);   
            // test last element of array
            univId = arrElem.getInt("id");
            univName = arrElem.getString("universityname");
            assertTrue(univId > 1 && univName.length() > 0);        
        }
    }
```

The above sample test case code from our project, does an HTTP GET database read only call. I'm looking for a database roll back solution for the test case, in case the REST API invoked by the test case did a database create/update/delete (i.e, just before or after the test case method exited, the database create/update/delete changes should roll back).

Comment: for integration test, try to use the in memory database like HSQL Database

Comment: Can you add a minimal example (source code) one of your integration tests?

Comment: add a @Transactional annotation on each of your test cases which change the db, then spring magic will take care of rollback.

Comment: adding a @Transactional annotation on test case will not help me. Since my test case is not connecting with the database directly or via a service method. My test case has an HTTP call to the REST API, and I wish to roll back database changes after each test case call.

Comment: @Nonika: I've added source code, of one of my test case in the body of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I tend to mark all my  @Test methods as @Transnational. But as your test case is completely detached from application context of course this will not help. spring has great integration test library for web layer [`MockMvc`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/). Using this library your test will look like:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApplnCommonRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getAllUniversitiesResponseBodyTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/appln-restapis/rest/public/common/getalluniversities"))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.data")
                        .value(iterableWithSize(2)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.data[0].id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.data[0].universityname", not(emptyArray())))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.data[1].id", greaterThan(1)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.data[1].universityname", not(emptyArray())));
    }
}
```

And also your test will rollback as this is not really external http call and `@Transactional` do work in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll attempt to write my integration tests using MockMvc, and would ask any doubts here, if I'm stuck.

Comment: Ok I'm here cant go outside COVID19 :)

Comment: I've tried using spring's MockMvc to write my tests. I'm facing one issue, for which I seek help here. In my test case method, following calls doesn't work, "MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(API_URI_1)
     .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + fAccessTokenAfterLogin)
     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))                      
     .andReturn();"   and I get http code 500 in this response. Any thoughts how can I fix this?

Comment: Hello do you use spring security?